# A pair that ignores the order for comparison operators

Tags: c++

Does anyone know of a way to make two pairs that have the same content but in different order be treated the same by a std::map? So the following:

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> Pair;
Pair pair1("first", "last");
Pair pair2("last", "first");

if (!(pair1 < pair2) && !(pair2 < pair1))
   std::cout << "I need this to happen please" << std::endl;
else
   std::cout << "boo" << std::endl;
```

I'm specifically interested in the less than operator (operator<). I've tried lots of stuff but every time I think that I got it, I find a case where the comparison doesn't work and causes std::map to have duplicate records or missing records.

My current workaround is to use std::set, which does what I need but in my case **I also need the order to stay the same as when the pair was created. Since std::set sorts everything, I can't use it.**

So to put it simply, solve operator< in the following:

```
struct MyPair
{
  std::string _First;
  std::string _Second;

  bool opreator<(const myPair &aRHS) const;
}
```

Here is what I tried (and many variations of it):

```
(_First < aRHS._First || (_First == aRHS._First && _Second < aRHS._Second )) ||
(_First < aRHS._Second || (_First == aRHS._Second && _Second < aRHS._First ))
```

I've currently given up (which explains why I'm here).

Comment: I don't see how this can possibly work......... I mean, you'd be _marginally_ closer if you paid enough attention to what you're doing to spell `operator` correctly, but only marginally.

Comment: If you think you need this, you are wrong. Revisit your overarching goal.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair

Comment: which cases fail with your comparison operator?

Comment: "Since std::set sorts everything..." So does `std::map`...

Comment: I don't have the cases that make that comparison fail any more, I abandoned this approach long time ago, I'll dig for the test cases but no promises. I had to ask because it was still bothering me enough. Sorry about the typos.

Comment: @Barry I sed the set to store _First and _Second. std::set<std::string> tMembers = {"first", "Last"} now the operator< will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One strategy to use:

1. Sort the first and second of each `MyPair`.
2. Compared the sorted first and second of the objects.

   ```
   bool MyPair::opreator<(const myPair &aRHS) const
   {
      lhsFirst = (this->_First < this_->_Second) ? this->_First : this->_Second;
      lhsSecond = (this->_First < this_->_Second) ? this->_Second : this->_First;

      rhsFirst = (aRHS._First < this_->_Second) ? aRHS._First : aRHS._Second;
      rhsSecond = (aRHS._First < this_->_Second) ? aRHS._Second : aRHS._First;

      if ( lhsFirst != rhsFirst )
      {
         return (lhsFirst < rhsFirst);
      }
      else
      {
         return (lhsSecond < rhsSecond);
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: You say "one strategy"...Is there another strategy to solve this problem other than sorting? Thanks

Comment: @rbhkamal, I didn't want to rule out any other strategies that may exist :) I have used the strategy I posted in different situations at my work.

Answer (score 0):

The following example first makes sure that `first` and `second` of `rhs` are sorted, **then** the two pairs are compared:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct OrderIndependentPair
{
  T1 first;
  T2 second;

  bool operator<(const OrderIndependentPair &rhs) const
  {
    if (rhs.first < rhs.second)
    {
        return std::tie(first, second) < std::tie(rhs.first, rhs.second);
    }
    else
    {
        return std::tie(first, second) < std::tie(rhs.second, rhs.first);
    }
  }
};

int main()
{
    using Pair = OrderIndependentPair<std::string, std::string>;

    using Map = std::map<Pair,int>;

    Map m;
    Pair p1{"foo", "bar"};
    m[p1] = 42;

    Pair p2{"bar", "foo"};
    std::cout << m[p1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << m[p2] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
42
42
```

**<kbd>[live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54844f7cbff3931c)</kbd>**

You can also use a `std::pair` and a custom comparator:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename Pair>
struct OrderIndependentPairComparison
{
    bool operator()(const Pair& lhs, const Pair& rhs) const
    {
        if (rhs.first < rhs.second)
        {
            return lhs < rhs;
        }
        else
        {
            return lhs < std::make_pair(rhs.second, rhs.first);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    using Pair = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;
    using Map = std::map<Pair,int, OrderIndependentPairComparison<Pair>>;

    Map m;
    Pair p1{"foo", "bar"};        
    Pair p2{"bar", "foo"};
    m[p1] = 42;
    std::cout << m[p1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << m[p2] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**<kbd>[live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/343e1910b54d1d7d)</kbd>**

Comment: Ahhh, I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks a lot, I can sleep better now.

Comment: That doesn't do enough. It does not take into account where `this->second` is less than `this->first`.

Comment: @RSahu do you have a case where it fails?

Comment: Yep, @RSahu is correct. I just tried both solutions and his works in areas where yours doesn't.

Comment: @rbhkamal please post these cases

Comment: Comparing (E1_BOTTOM, E1_TOP) or (DC_TOP, DC_BOTTOM) with (E1_TOP, DC_BOTTOM).  So if a map has either one of the first two pairs, you can't insert the the third.